# Particles disappear in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to make a space flying game, 
but there is something weird going on.

When the camera reaches -1800 my geometry seems to disappear.

What am I doing wrong?

Three.js r87

```
var container, debug, renderer, camera, scene;
var geometry, particle, material, pointcloud;
var particleCount = 1000;
var keys = {up:false,down:false};

function init() {
    container = document.getElementById('wrapper');
    debug = document.getElementById('debug');

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 3000);
    camera.position.z = 2000;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    for (var p = 0; p < particleCount; p++) {
        particle = new THREE.Vector3(Math.random()*2000-1000, Math.random()*2000-1000, Math.random()*2000-1000);
        geometry.vertices.push(particle);
    }
    material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({size:2, color:0xffffff, transparent:true, depthWrite:false});
    pointcloud = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
    scene.add(pointcloud);

    animate();

    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 38) keys.up = true;
        if(e.keyCode == 40) keys.down = true;
    });
    document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 38) keys.up = false;
        if(e.keyCode == 40) keys.down = false;
    });
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    if(keys.up == true) camera.position.z -= 50;
    if(keys.down == true) camera.position.z += 50;

    for(var i = 0; i<particleCount; i++) {
        particle = geometry.vertices[i];
        if(!!particle && particle.z > camera.position.z) {
            particle.z = camera.position.z-(Math.random()*2000-1000);
        }
    }
    geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
    geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true;

    debug.innerHTML = camera.position.z;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

init();
```

Click on the canvas, then press up and down arrow to move the camera:
https://jsfiddle.net/c056ahs2/2/

Comment: Interestingly enough, setting the camera position to -2000, renders the points correctly. When you get to about -3800, it fails again.

Comment: Setting `camera.position.z = -1800;` worked fine for me. Note that you're using a fixed depth. `camera.near` is `1` and `camera.far` is `3000`. These are in units from the camera's position. So if a point is `0.5` or `3001` units away from the camera, it will be clipped by the respective plane, and won't render. These values also control your depth precision. The greater the difference, the more problems you'll encounter, like z-fighting. Try using a  [logarithmic depth buffer](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_camera_logarithmicdepthbuffer.html) instead.

Comment: Set the camera to -1800, and travel, you will have the same problem.
Even with 'logarithmicDepthBuffer' set to true, and the near and far extremely high

Comment: @TheJim01 Not sure why that comment is relevant.

Comment: What happens when you increase your camera.far to say... 5000?

Comment: @Hobbes Same result, they disappear around -1800. Play around with the fiddle to see the problem